# jQuery trigger incrementing radio:checked length at a -1 offset

Tags: jquery

Instead of doing `for` to change the state of a radio button when the label is clicked, I am using jQuery. I also have another event attached to the radio button where I count the amount of radio buttons that are checked.

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('input:radio').trigger('click');
});

$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').length);
});
```

the console log of `length` is `0` when the first radio is clicked, then `1` when second is clicked, and so on...

What am I missing?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `change` event instead.

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('input:radio').trigger('click');
});

$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
    console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').length);
});
```

Though I wouldn't use jQuery for the label when you could just do this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group">click me</label>
```

Comment: This is an update to about 30 pages that run the same js. So it will save me an hour or 2 if I just do it with javascript instead of edit each page's html. Thanks. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

The checked state of a radio button only changes *after* the click handler returns.

This is necessary because the handler might return `false` or call `preventDefault()` in order to inhibit the default behavior of the control. If the checked state was modified before the handler returned, it would be impossible to inhibit the default behavior (as it would already have taken place).

You can use [window.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a `0` delay to schedule your call to `console.log()` after the handler has returned:

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($("input[type=radio]:checked").length);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: thanks for this. Made a lot more sense with your explanation. I am going to use @RightSaidFred answer because it's easier and also works but I appreciate the detail.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` is simply a UI action. The event you should be handling on your radio input is `change`.